# Spring Post method with relational database (RestApi)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, many-to-one

I have a problem, i don't know how to create relational database in Hibernate and how to create json i post method.

I want to get through exist teacher with new student and I want to find all students who have particular teacher. I want to create something like foreign key to teacher in student table.

My code:

BaseEntity

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

}
```

Student

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Teacher teacher;
...
}
```

Teacher

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
...
}
```

TeacherController

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addTeacher(@RequestBody Teacher teacher) {
        teacherService.addTeacher(teacher);
    }
```

StudentController

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
        studentService.addStudent(student);
    }
```

My JSon body when i create a teacher:

```
{
    "name" : "Test"
}
```

Should student post method look like this?

```
{
        "name": "TestStudent",
        "teacher": {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "Test"
        }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, you need to separate Student and student in your addStudent method.

Comment: @OcelotcR Done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kubek ,If this is your web-application and you are doing this from UI (view) side then you can put combo box of Teacher's list and then upon selecting that teacher that id you can pass into the form like below :
{
        "name": "TestStudent",
        "teacher": {
            "id": 1
        }
}

this will automatically find Teacher object (id) and will save it into db.

Comment: when i post: { "name": "TestStudent", "teacher": { "id": 1 } } i have got error: {
    "timestamp": "2019-04-26T05:25:56.008+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"add\"",
    "path": "/student/add"
}

Comment: @Kubek, Have you added break point in Controller to check what values you are getting on Controller side ? If not then please check data type first ! Still you get the error then please share stack trace and code.

Comment: I have post method:  @RequestMapping(name = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addStudent(@RequestBody Student student){ studentService.addStudent(student);} Should I change something, becouse i have object (entity) student in RequestBody.

Comment: @Kubek ,I have another solution for this..this is my code which was working fine for me.  @PostMapping(value = "/event/add", consumes = { "application/json" })
     public ResponseEntity<Void> addEvent(@RequestBody(required = false) EventDto eventdto)

Comment: Second thing : Try to use DTO Object(Temporary POJO of retreive and view purpose) in your controller instead of main POJO if possible.So that end user can not view your whole POJO and there remains a layer of abstraction.

If you are using DTO Object then  `{"name": "TestStudent", "teacher_id": 1 }`  will be your input to controller.Let me know it works or not.

Comment: It's work, I thought about this solution before. Thank you :)